# How to show the field names with their values in editable format while clicking the edit button?

Tags: html

I'm using html for designing my webpage. In that I am having one requirement. that is I need to display the field
names with their values in editable format in different window while clicking the edit button. Can anyone help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Be a bit more specific..what are the "fields"? what's the problem you're facing?

Comment: Do you have any sample code? In a HTML page you can do editing in a textbox or textarea. You can set the textbox to readonly when not in edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i've understood from your question. You can perhaps append a `<span><input type='text' id='EditVal'></span>` to the innerHTML of the current field selected. And when the enter key is pressed or anywhere outside the area is clicked. You can save the current "Editval" value and display it as the edited text. I hope i cleared your doubt.